# How to refactor path names like `AppBundle:SomeFolder:someFile` in Symfony 2/3 based project to be used in Symfony 4+?

Tags: php, symfony

I am working on a Symfony project which was started based on `Symfony 2` and currently uses `Symfony 3.4`. A lot of code in the project specifies paths using the : notation, for example:

```
$this->render('AppBundle:Products:products_list.html.twig');
// ==> /path/to/project/src/AppBundle/Resources/views/Products/products_list.html.twig

$this->getRepository('AppBundle:Products\Product');
// ==> /path/to/project/src/AppBundle/Entiy/Products/Product.php
```

The Project should now be updated to Symfony 5. Since Bundles are not (should be) used any more, a lot of these paths will change and need to be updated.

Doing this for entity classes is not a big deal, the `::class` notation can be used without specifying any path:

```
$this->getRepository(Product::class);
```

But how to update all the other paths which do not represent a path but some asset or config file, etc.? Is there any rule of thumb on how `'AppBundle:Products:products_list.html.twig'` should be updated when it is moved to `/path/to/project/templates/app/products/products_list.html.twig`?

---

EDIT:

Of course I can manually update all paths, e.g. from `AppBundle:Products:products_list.html.twig` to `app/products/products_list.html.twig`. Although some search/replace in all sources files might help, this is a cumbersome process.

Updating the class paths, e.g. from `'AppBundle:Products\Product'` to `Product::class` also need manually work, but this approach has two major advantages:

1. The search/replace could be done in while still working with Symfony 3.4. The changes could be tested before performing the update. When updated to Symfony 5 no  further changes would necessary, the `MyEntity::class` notation would simply deliver the new paths.
2. The path is not hard coded. If the file location changes again, no further updated is required.

Of course I am aware that these advantages are a benifit of using the `::class` method. The question is, if there is any way in Symfony to achieve (nearly) the same for non-class files, like assets, config files, etc. Or is hard cording the paths the way to go?

Comment: to `$this->render('app/products/products_list.html.twig');

Comment: Thanks @SubCore, this is obviously correct. I have edited the question to make it more clear: Is hard coding the paths the best way to go or is there a better way?

Comment: Thats matter of opinion. If you don't want to use relative pathes, you can use Template-Namespaces like `@products/products_list.html.twig`. Thats a little config in twig.yaml

Comment: Take a look at [twig namespaces](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/templating/namespaced_paths.html).  Even under 3.4, running 'console debug:twig' should show you that the '@App' namespace points to your template directory.  So '@App/products/products_list.html.twig' should work under 3.4.  The same sort of thing will work under the [latest and greatest Symfony 5.2](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#template-namespaces).

Comment: If you have a great deal of code to upgrade then you might try this [rector tool](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector).  I hesitate to recommend it because I have never used it on 'real' code.  Just messed around a bit.  But the author is quite active and quite a few developers seem to use it.